# why is Homebrew not finding a formula?

Tags: homebrew

What could be going on here? I am clueless. Homebrew cannot find `brewsci/base/rstudio-server`. It does find other formulas on that tap. The `rstudio-server.rb` script is correctly named and in the right folder.

I have two formulas in the brewsci tap. One is `boost-rstudio-server`. brew finds that one. It does not find `rstudio-server`, but it's in the same tap.

```
me@iMac Formula $ brew install rstudio-server 

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly named formulae were found:
brewsci/base/boost-rstudio-server ✔
brewsci/base/rstudio-server
lab/base/boost-rstudio-server-1.3 ✔
lab/base/drop-rstudio-server

Error: No available formula or cask with the name "rstudio-server".
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

me@iMac Formula $ brew install brewsci/base/rstudio-server
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "brewsci/base/rstudio-server".
```

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the syntax issue in the tap

```
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/brewsci/homebrew-base/Formula/rstudio-server.rb
rstudio-server: Calling depends_on :java is disabled! Use "depends_on "openjdk@11", "depends_on "openjdk@8" or "depends_on "openjdk" instead.
Please report this issue to the brewsci/base tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/brewsci/homebrew-base/Formula/rstudio-server.rb:36

Error: Cannot tap brewsci/base: invalid syntax in tap!
```

#### Fix for searching the formula

The workaround is to manually checkout the tap

- `mkdir -p /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/brewsci/homebrew-base`
- `cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/brewsci/homebrew-base`
- `git clone https://github.com/brewsci/homebrew-base .`

And then you can find the formula

```
$ brew search rstudio-server
==> Formulae
brewsci/base/boost-rstudio-server                     brewsci/base/rstudio-server
```

I dont have a linux machine to test out the actual installation, let me know if `brew install` works or not.